# How do I get the asincio current time? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to get curent time in async

I have code:

```py
async def get_hour():
    return datetime.datetime.now().hour

async def timer():
    while True:
        print(await get_hour())
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

asyncio.run(timer())
```

He is working, but another code don't working in async.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regular, non-async operations. Getting the current time isn't some slow I/O-bound operation where you need to let other code run while it's happening. It's like how we don't have async versions of addition or multiplication.

Comment: The problem is that I need to constantly get the time and when the right time comes, then execute a certain code. How to do this without an infinite loop, I do not know how

Comment: @SapeNeCo: "Wait for a certain time" is a very different operation from "get the current time". If that's what you were having problems with, you should have asked a question about that, not about getting the current time.

Comment: If you want to wait for a certain time, you've already found the correct tool to do that: `asyncio.sleep`, a function you already called in the code you posted.

Comment: yes, I did the waiting, but the problem is that while it is waiting, all the rest of the asynchronous code is not working

Comment: @SapeNeCo: Either you used `time.sleep` instead of `asyncio.sleep`, or you have some other bug. If it wasn't the `time.sleep` thing, you can ask a new question about your bug. Make sure to include code in your new question that actually reproduces the bug when run.